# Video is not getting displayed as per the position set in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to display video full screen initially and if user presses 'm' key, Need to display a div with a text and immediately down the text, I need to display the video. when I press 'm', even though I am setting width and height, Video is not getting displayed in the full width and height I have set and event the text is not getting displayed in side the div. Below is the code.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VOD</title>
        <script src='lib/hls.js'></script>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                height:100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: dimgray;
            }

            #header {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
            }

            #vid.full {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: 3;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            #vid.pip {
                position: fixed;
                left: 50px;
                top: 50px;
                width: 320px;
                height: 256px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='header' style="display:none">
            <h2>DVR</h2>
        </div>
        <video id='vid' src='textMotion.mp4'class='full' autoplay></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript:**

```
    function displayMenu() {
    // If already menu is visible, hide it
    let vid = document.getElementById('vid');
    let hid = document.getElementById('header');

    if(vid.classList.contains('pip') == true) {
        hid.style.display = 'none';
        vid.classList.add('full');
        vid.classList.remove('pip');
        return;
    }

    hid.style.display = 'block';
    vid.classList.add('pip');
    vid.classList.remove('full');
}

function processKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('received keyEvent : ' + e.keyCode);
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;

    // Menu button or key 'm'
    if((keyCode == 77) || (keyCode == 462)) {
        displayMenu();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyPress);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

When user selects 'm', video pip should be displayed immediately under 'header' element. But as per the screenshot, there is lot of gap visible between video and header. When I inspect the element video element is right under header. But it is not visible. I think it is because of aspect ratio. Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue. How can we make sure that video should be fully displayed in the given width and height.